# Отчёт из двух выборок данных

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, fastreport

Есть отчёт. В зависимости от условия он может строиться либо по одной выборке, либо по другой, либо нужно соединить обе выборки. Количество полей идентичны, разница только в источнике данных. Отчёт строиться в фаст репорте. В c# выполняется запрос а в fastreport подбрасывается xml, и xsd фалы.

Как мне реализовать в зависимости от условия что бы отчёт строился на разных выборках и на обоих вместе. В fastreport уже создал 2 источника данных. Что делать дальше пока не могу понять.

Comment: мб хранимая процедура с параметром решит вашу проблему? будет у вас всегда один источник данных, который сам решит откуда и что брать, и в каком виде показывать

Comment: @teran, процедура не подходит, нужно решить это именно запросом. Как то наверное средствами fastreport можно реализовать то что я хочу. Вот и хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: @teran а как вы предлагаете хранимкой? Ради интереса. Вот есть у меня aspx страница. С неё в фаст репорт отправляется xsd схема. И результаты выборки запроса. Но в зависимости от кейса запросы разные и к разным таблицам. Как можно разграничить? Какой в фаст репорте будет обрабатываться запрос?  И какой источник данных будет использоваться. Вся загвоздка в самом фаст репорте.

Comment: дак вот кейс этот и запихайте в хранимку

Comment: т.е. вам просто надо напечатать по сути два отчета подряд в случае "на обоих вместе"?

Comment: Если вы хотите печатать в одном отчёте, значит у вас одинаковая структура данных, или как еще? А если у вас одинаковая структура, то объедините данные средствами бд, ну или c# в крайнем случае.